# Smarty - Difficult if else to make select options

Tags: foreach, smarty, if-statement

I am having real trouble getting my head around this smarty else if. 
For each

```
{foreach $values as $value}

 {if $value = a}
     do action
 {elseif $value = b}
     do action
 {elseif $value = c}
     do action
 {/if}

{/foreach}
```

I only want to 'do action' once for the entire foreach. For any one iteration of the foreach a differnt condition(a b or c) might be = to $value

The real world example that I am working on is adding 'selected' to a drop down option.

```
<select>
    {foreach $offices as $office}<!-- The if below is done so that the form is sticky, and when editing a post, it shows the post's current setting.-->

         <option 

         {if $smarty.post.OfficeCode == $office.OfficeCode}
              selected='selected'
         {elseif $bulletin_array[0].OfficeCode == $office.OfficeCode}
              selected='selected'
         {elseif $office.OfficeCode == $UsersOffice}
              selected='selected'
         {/if}                 

        title='{$office.Description}' value='{$office.OfficeCode}'>{$office.Title}  
</option>

    {/foreach}
</select>
```

the first if will be true if the form has been submited - to make the form sticky
the second part will be true the form is being pre-filled when editing the record - ie prefil the form with the current value
the third part will be true if the user is creating a new record, in which case set it to a default option that the user usually uses. 
I need some way of only allowing selected to be added once. 
I php I would have a variable outside the foreach which was set to true if selected was added. I would then check that variable before doing the if elseif

Answer (score 1):

```
{if ($smarty.post.OfficeCode eq $office.OfficeCode) 
  or ($bulletin_array[0].OfficeCode eq $office.OfficeCode) 
  or ($office.OfficeCode eq $UsersOffice)}
    selected='selected'
{/if}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because at least one option would be true for each of the options. This would mean that all the options would be marked as selected

Comment: You answer would actually make the problem occur more often. I think I have it figured it out. I will post a response when I have checked it.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, so it was hard to understand where you wanted `selected` to appear once - within the `option` or within the `option`s in the `select`. Anyway, the question sounded like `IF` related, so I provided the optimized solution. What you want can be achieved only through an additional variable, whatever language you're using. And simply include the variable in the boolean expression to get the right result.

Comment: On the other hand, where's the logic? You have multiple options that meet the criteria. What's the difference if the first or the last is selected? If you mark more than one as selected, the last one will be selected. It also meets the criteria. Maybe you need a select `multiple`?

Comment: Because when you select two select options, whichever one comes last will be the one which is selected and that makes no sense.

Comment: Why no sense? What sense does it make for the first to be the one that's selected? :) Why is first better than last?